# Make textarea fullsize

Tags: html, css

I'm doing some kinds of form and I have this problem.

I'm planning to divided my page into 3 columns (2 aside with pic and the middle will have a little form. So I put the textarea in the form and but the column and row number in the HTML file. However, when I try to format the scale of the column, the problem pops up. The size of the column is not the size of textarea. Anyway for me to make the textarea full size, compatible with the column?

[image: This one is the one where I get rid of the column part]

```css
    #left,

    #right,

    #form {

      width: 31%;

      float: right;

    }
```

```html
<section id="left">
  <img src="./image/left.JPG" />
</section>
<section id="form">
  <form>
    <textarea id="message" rows="4" width="120"></textarea>
  </form>
</section>
<section id="right">
  <img src="./image/right.JPG" />
</section>
```

Comment: Create a fiddle or codepen please. Do not be a nasty boy/girl/whatever.

Comment: textareas have no `width` attribute. they have `rows` and `cols`.

Comment: @MarcB orly? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyLpZz

Comment: You're using **CSS** width. OP has `width="xxx"` in the tag attributes. Utterly different things.

Comment: @MarcB oops, sorry, didn't notice your talking bout attribute.

Comment: @youdon'tknow sorry I have never used them. Sorry for the mess, will learn how to use that later. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I am supposed to but row and col but I throw col out when I'm freaking out about the width. When I put up here I put them in again but get it wrong.

Comment: you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mavvb0vu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#left, #right, #form
{
    width: 31%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<section id="left"><img src="./image/left.JPG"/></section>
<section id="form">
    <form>
        <textarea id="message" rows="4" style="width:100%;" ></textarea>
    </form>
</section>
<section id="right"><img src="./image/right.JPG"/></section>
```

If you set the width to 100% for your text area then it will fill the area that it is in.

Comment: Whoever down-voted, if you leave a note explaining why then I might be able to fix my post. This seems to be exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: This is not the case. If I set 100% then it's not the column anymore!

Comment: Because your ``style="width: 100%;"`` is not solving the problem. Since still it will take 100% of the 31%-widthed ``#form`` parent.

Comment: @TreeNguyen Maybe you could clarify the problem more. It was my understanding, that you were trying to get the textarea to match the size of the column. That is what my solution does.

Comment: @Shriike yep your's absolutely correct. I forget (not sure to be exact) that the textarea inherit the 31% width :). Thanks :)